# Having the right selectors for span with two classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

*HTML

```
<div id='board'>
<div>
    abc<span class='openCurly bm1'>{</span>
</div>
<div>
    'jkl'm<span  class='openParen bm2' >(</span>no<span class='closeParen bm2'>)</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class= 'closeCurly bm1'>}</span>
</div>
```

*JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#board").on("mouseenter mouseover", "[class*=bm]", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        $("." + className).addClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
    $("#board").on("mouseleave mouseout", "[class*=bm]", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[0];
        $("." + className).removeClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
});
```

*CSS

```
.curlyHighlight {
background-color: red;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

When i hover to either { or }, it will highlight both of them (partners). Same thing as hovering either ( or ). Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/10/

Comment: `class="class1" class="class2"` is not valid HTML. You cannot specify the same attribute twice. Use `class="class1 class2"` instead.

Comment: I like questions with no question in it. And nothing happens in your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your idea correctly, you are trying to highlight matching brackets. I point out something in your code.

First, your `class` property is not valid, you should combine them into one place.

```
<div id='board'>
    <div>
        abc<span class='openCurly bm1'>{</span> <!-- an example of merged classes -->
    </div>
    <div>
        'jkl'm<span  class='openParen bm2' >(</span>no<span class='closeParen bm2'>)</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class= 'closeCurly bm1'>}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second, I think you choose the wrong class to apply the effect, the correct index should be `1` (so the selected classes will be `bm1` or `bm2` instead of `openCurly` as current)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#board").on("mouseenter mouseover", "[class*=bm]", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]; // index 1 instead of 0
        $("." + className).addClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
    $("#board").on("mouseleave mouseout", "[class*=bm]", function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').split(" ")[1]; // index 1 instead of 0
        $("." + className).removeClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/12/)

Comment: Relying on the order of the class names seems like a really bad idea that is very likely to break as the code changes. The OP should probably look for `bm1` or `bm2` instead

Comment: @JuanMendes Yes, I prefer using `data` property for holding information. I have just modified hist code as less as possible.

Comment: I understand, just warning the OP. I would use `var className = $(this).attr('class').match(/bm[\d]/)[0];` http://jsfiddle.net/yxVd9/15/

Comment: @juanMendes bm0, bm1... 2345 etc is not about the order, i just want to pair them that is suited to my design (yes i know the design of my system is a bit messy)

Comment: @trung-hieule what's really about that data-class? y do u prefer it? (found few sources on google)

Comment: @fireflieslive It is a new way to contain your private data come with HTML5, here is a good article about it http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one attribute of class for the element. It is invalid and will apply only the first instance of class attribute.

```
<span class='closeParen' class='bm2'>)<
```

Supposed to be :

```
    <span class='closeParen  bm2'>)<
```

---

And as for the selector you can use this:

```
`$('.closeParen.bm2')` to select the span
```

---

Fix your HTML first; it's supposed to like this:

```
<div id='board'>
    <div>
       abc<span class='openCurly bm1'>{</span>
    </div>
    <div>
     'jkl'm<span  class='openParen bm2' >(
         </span>no<span class='closeParen bm2'>)</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <span class= 'closeCurly bm1'>}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

You can just reference the element using `this` context instead of finding the class.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#board").on("mouseenter mouseover", "[class*=bm]", function() {
        $(this).addClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
    $("#board").on("mouseleave mouseout", "[class*=bm]", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("curlyHighlight");
    });
});
```

The problem with the way you have written is you are selecting the elements directly using a class. So it will select all the elements of that class irrespective of the one over which it is hovered. Using `this` should take care of the issue.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/yxVd9/13/)**

Both the events can be bound to the selector with a single selection.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#board").on({
      mouseenter: function () {
          $(this).addClass("curlyHighlight");
      },
      mouseleave: function () {
          $(this).removeClass("curlyHighlight");
      }
        }, "[class*=bm]");
     });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't match the brackets/parens, that's why the OP was creating a new jQuery object containing both brackets, so they can be highlighted